# Data binding, multithreading, and unit testing

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, unit-testing, data-binding

I have a model that is data bound to controls in a view. One of the bound properties (of type `BindingList<T>`) gets updated from another thread.

With help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874482/can-i-safely-bind-to-data-on-multi-threaded-applications/2874590#2874590), I solved the *"Cross-thread operation not valid"* issue as follows (.NET 4.0, TPL):

```
public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly TaskFactory _uiThreadTaskFactory =
        new TaskFactory(TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

    private readonly object _myPropertyLocker = new object();

    private void Handler()
    {
        // In another thread

        _uiThreadTaskFactory.StartNew(
            () =>
                {
                    lock (_myPropertyLocker)
                    {
                        MyProperty.Add(someStuff);
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

This worked - until I tried to run my unit tests in ReSharper's test runner (v5.1). They threw the error

> The current SynchronizationContext may not be used as a TaskScheduler.

on line

```
new TaskFactory(TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

How can I resolve this as elegantly as possible?

Comment: Are you using NUnit? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8245926/nunit-tests-the-current-synchronizationcontext-may-not-be-used-as-a-taskschedul

Comment: @LukeHutton - yes, NUnit. I think you found the issue. You might want to post that as an answer. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide a SynchronizationContext. **Reference:** [The current SynchronizationContext may not be used as a TaskScheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8245926/nunit-tests-the-current-synchronizationcontext-may-not-be-used-as-a-taskschedul).

```cs
[SetUp]
public void TestSetUp()
{
  SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new SynchronizationContext());
}
```

Comment: I ended up injecting a TaskScheduler into my model via the constructor - in production I pass `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()`, in tests I pass `TaskScheduler.Current`.

Comment: Update: `CurrentThreadTaskScheduler` from [Samples for Parallel Programming with the .NET Framework](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ParExtSamples/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx) works better for testing than `TaskScheduler.Current`.